# SQL Server: how to create zero table with certain dimensions n and m?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sparse-matrix

Suppose you want `n` rows and `m` columns. Zero table is a table with all values equal to zero. You want to create an zero table of the dimensions `n` times `m`. How can you create a zero table with dimensions `n` and `m` in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Explain what a "zero table" is .....

Comment: @marc_s zero table is a table where all values are equal to zero.

Comment: show us an example of how that table looks like. What are the fieldnames?

Comment: Why do you need this? Is SQL Server the right tool for the job?

Comment: Is this related to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43694372/2333499

Comment: @SqlZim partly but I want to keep them separate to have clear generic focus to be more helpful to others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically creating a table of 0s:

```
declare @n int = 10; /* rows */
declare @m int = 10; /* columns */

declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

select @cols = stuff((
    select top (@m) ',' + quotename(n) + ' = 0'
    from (
      select n=row_number() over (order by (select 1)) 
      from master..spt_values
      ) t
    order by n
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'');

select @sql = '
select ' + @cols + '
from (
  select top (@n) n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))
  from master..spt_values
  ) t
';

select @sql as CodeGenerated;
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@n int', @n;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PKLUA61633

returns:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                      CodeGenerated                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| select [1] = 0,[2] = 0,[3] = 0,[4] = 0,[5] = 0,[6] = 0,[7] = 0,[8] = 0,[9] = 0,[10] = 0 |
| from (                                                                                  |
|   select top (@n) n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))                             |
|   from master..spt_values                                                               |
|   ) t                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and the `exec sp_executesql` returns:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create tables with default values as 0 as @SQLZim mentioned and create insert scripts with default values. As below

```
 create table #test ([1] int default 0, [2] int default 0)

 insert into #test ([1],[2]) default values
```

Comment: This is actually very cool: so in SQL Server Management Studio, I can use Data Import, for example to import a sparse csv file, and its the Advanced tab to create default 0?